# Add file to PATH only when in specific directory

Tags: bash, environment-variables, path, cd-command, pwd

Is it possible to make executable appear in the global search path when I am entering to the some specific directory and get it removed once directory changed again?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking (due to poor grammar: I can to parse your sentence).

Comment: Are you asking “How do I make it so that the current-working-directory is in the executable search PATH?” If so then don't do it. It will cause you pain (this used to be the default  (it still is on Microsoft's windows), but it leads to errors, and security vulnerabilities.